# list file that match time range using unix time stamp

Tags: bash, list, match

These files contains unix time as part of their name.
these files are as below:

1.1437039767.xml
1.1437039614.xml
etc..

Here is my bash function; I am trying to list only files that their name are between Today and tomorrow in unix time.

```
list () {

D=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00")
d=$(date -d "${D}" +%s)
CURRENT=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
u=$(date -d "${CURRENT}" +%s)

LS=$(ls -1A "${1}"* | sed -e "s/1.//" -e "s/.xml$//")

for file in ${LS};
do
if [ "${file}" -gt "${d}" -a "${file}" -lt "${u}" ];
then
echo "1.${file}.xml"
fi
done
}

list ${1}
```

This function gives such of error

```
[: 16-07-15/1437025363: integer expression expected
```

Any help :)

Adding the output with the -x

Here is my command including ${1}:

```
./test.sh /path/

+ '[' path/1437043449 -gt 1437001200 -a path/1437043449 -lt 1437057123 ']'
./test.sh: line 17: [: path/1437043449: integer expression expected
```

Thank you.
Al.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the start of your function so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are leaving the directory name in the numbers
you try to compare, eg `path/1437043449 -gt 1437001200` when you 
should be comparing simply `1437043449 -gt 1437001200`.

I've edited your script to use `expr` instead of sed to extract just the
number part from the complete pathname (the part inside `\(...\)`).

```
list () {
    D=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00")
    d=$(date -d "${D}" +%s)
    u=$(date +%s)

    for file in $(ls -1A "${1}"*)
    do if    number=$(expr "$file" : '.*\.\([0-9]*\)\.xml$')
       then  if [ "$number" -ge "${d}" -a "$number" -le "${u}" ]
             then   echo "$file"
             fi
       fi
    done
}
list ${1}
```